# mouse move event not working in mozilla

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this i have a background image on body and with following script when the moves the image in background also moves.
css for this is

```
      body
    {
background-image:url('../images/1.png');
background-size:98%;
background-position:center top;
background-repeat:no-repeat;

  } 


         <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#big').mousemove(function(e){
         var mousePosX = (e.pageX/$(window).width())*100;
         $('#big').css('background-position-x', mousePosX +'%');
          var mousePosY = (e.pageY/$(window).height())*100;
         $('#big').css('background-position-y', mousePosY +'%');
         console.log(mousePosX, mousePosY);
       }); 
      });
     </script>
```

My problem is that this code perfectly works in chrome but its not working in mozilla firefox so how can i achieve this... plz help me out

Answer (score 0):

`background-position-x` only works in webkit browsers, you can however use `background-position` and declare both in the same line:

```
  var mousePosX = (e.pageX/$(window).width())*100;
  var mousePosY = (e.pageY/$(window).height())*100;
  $('#big').css('background-position', mousePosX +'%' + ' ' + mousePosY +'%');
```